# howto find the correct size of the visual vieport in the browser, instead of window.innerHeight and similar

Tags: layout, window-size, layout-viewport

Often, window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight give unsatisfying values, as in [this example](https://cloc3.net/varie/testBrowserLayout).

In the same example, I use a workaround to adapt exactly a div to the browser visual layout (the class hackedWindowSizes, based on element.getBoundingClientRect ), but I don't like it vary much.

Is there a standard instrument to make the same thing?